# How to choose the 12 prior weeks in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

It had a lot of row with NULL value which I deleted using the following query:

```
/* DELETE EVERY ROW EXCEPT THE ROW WE NEED */
DELETE FROM [Database].[dbo].[Table]
    WHERE
    ([Week Of*] IS NULL)
```

How do I write a query which will get the prior 12 weeks from the current rolling week and insert the `[F4]` value into a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following which gave me the last 12 weeks (how ever I have to use `14` to get the 12 weeks. Still trying to figure out why:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Week Of*],110) AS [Date], [F18] AS [TOTALS] FROM [db].[DBO].[table] WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Week Of*],110) >= DATEADD(week, -14, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT f4
FROM yourtable
WHERE DATEADD(week, -12, [Week Of*]) >= 12
```

Comment: Maybe I have to convert the `[Week of*]` to correct format in the query? I am still getting the same row :/

Comment: ah. so you want within 12 weeks of "today"? then `dateadd(..., current_timestamp) >= [Week of*]`

Comment: Yep... I want to get the row of the 12 weeks before this current week... So it would start from 1-31 to 3-31. Where should I add that?

Comment: Constructive Criticism: @MarcB Will it be not better to write this where clause as `WHERE [Week Of*] <= DATEADD(week, -12, GETDATE())`, This makes it sargable query :)

Comment: @M.Ali Can you please clarify a bit more?

Comment: @SiKni8 Read this post for explanation [`SARGable functions in SQL Server`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server.aspx)